# Android audio lag while playing MPEG-TS file

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, mpeg2-ts

I've recently been struggling a lot with playback of a video inside an Android app. The video in question is an M3U8 file, which in turn links to a series of secondary M3U8s, each of which has a list of component MPEG-TS video files, and a single M3U8 file containing the audio components in AAC format. I had a fair bit of trouble making M3U8 cooperate, however that now seems to be working OK.

Unfortunately, the audio is lagging about a second behind the video. This lag is present both in my own Activity containing a MediaPlayer, and simply launching Android's default video player pointing to the stream. There is also frequent visual stuttering or corruption in the playback. Neither issue is present when played with VLC Beta, or in the iPhone version of this app, hence it's not a problem with the video file itself. I tried the Vitamio library, this ran even worse (far more frequent corruption, and no audio at all). Regrettably, changing the video format is not an option.

It seems to me that this issue may be caused by Android's limited support for MPEG-TS - the list of supported media formats specifies that it uses the AAC audio (whereas I assume the iOS version is simply playing both video and audio from the .ts file). Any recommendations/solutions for fixing this lag?

Comment: most ts files have an audio delay relative to their video. Either repackage the stream (using ffmpeg) ffmpeg -i {input} -c copy -f mpegts out.ts or change settings on the encoder that produces the stream.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Gstreamer which seems to work well on Android (http://gstreamer.com/), also Vitamio is